# MariaDB: No database selected error on some query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, php, common-table-expression, prepared-statement

I have a php code that rise a query against a **MariaDB** (using MariaDB 10.5.11 on debian 11) table; I use php-mysql prepared queries for this task as reported in the code below:

```
if($this->dbcon->begin_transaction() === false) {
        $this->errNum = -1;
        $this->errText = "Unable to start transaction: " . $this->dbcon->errno . " - " . $this->dbcon->error;
        return false;
}

try {
    $query = file_get_contents("recursivelyRemoveShares.sql");   // (1) If replaced with a SELECT works fine!

    if($query === false) {
        $this->errNum = -1;
        $this->errText = "Unable to read query (0)";
        return false;
    }

    $stmt = $this->dbcon->prepare($query);      // Err 1046: No database selected
    if($stmt === false) {
        $this->errNum = -1;
        $this->errText = "Unable to prepare statement: " . $this->dbcon->errno . " - " . $this->dbcon->error;
        return false;
    }
    
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $uuid);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Commit transaction
    $this->dbcon->commit();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Rollback transaction if something goes wrong
    $this->dbcon->rollback();
    
    $this->errNum = $this->dbcon->errno;
    $this->errText = $this->dbcon->error;
    return false;
}
```

When running `$stmt = $this->dbcon->prepare($query);` the database raise an `Err 1046: No database selected`; however I did some other operations before that executed successfully, using the same DB connection.

This is the query I read with `file_get_contents`:

```
DELETE FROM `shares` WHERE `itemuuid` in (
  WITH RECURSIVE files_paths (id, parent) AS
  (
    SELECT uuid, parentuuid
      FROM core_data
      WHERE uuid = ?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.uuid, e.parentuuid
      FROM files_paths AS ep JOIN core_data AS e
        ON ep.id = e.parentuuid
  )
  SELECT id FROM files_paths
)
```

Note that is a recursive CTE query.

If I replace the $query with a SELECT query, all the code runs correctly (no error 1046 raisen).

Any help or idea is appreciated.

**Monday Sept 13 edit!!**

Same code tested on MySQL 8 works fine! Just removed MariaDB and installed MySQL8, no changes on php codes or SQL queries! Is this a MariaDB issue?

Comment: Where are you telling PHP which database to use? Also, what does your SELECT query look like?

Comment: add the databse to your connection parameters alternativly you can use ùse databasename`directly after coonncting

Comment: Which version of php, which mysql client library?

Comment: Obviously in precedent code not posted here:

```$DBCON = new mysqli($connectionParams['host'], $connectionParams['user'], $connectionParams['password'], $connectionParams['dbname'], $connectionParams['port']);``` then appropriately passed as parameters to the class constructor. @dbdemon @nbk

Comment: @GerardH.Pille php 7.4 and MariaDB 10.5.11 using php-mysqli

Comment: @dbdemon simple ```SELECT COUNT(uuid) FROM mytable``` - Just to test if it's the code failing or the query itself... or... whatever!

Comment: The connection have a property which sets a command executed each time the connection is established. Add `USE databasename` into this property value.

Comment: Even simpler:  `SELECT 1 FROM mytable`.

Comment: No special characters inside "recursivelyRemoveShares.sql" ?  If not, can you create a db fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille nothing... read my amendment to my question!

Comment: If you provide a db fiddle I'll try to reproduce it with MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be a MariaDB issue. Here's why I believe so:

### *** STAR WARS MUSIC START UP ***

### *** SCREEN TILTS AND WORDS SCROLL UP AND SAYS ... ***

Over 10 years ago, I wrote an answer to the post [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384). In that post someone asked why a DELETE on a table with a subquery against the same table would not work. I had found something in the MySQL Internals Documentation that explains how a query can be rewritten in such a way that key values can virtually disappear while rows are being processed. In your case, I would speculate that one or more missing keys due to a transformation could be incorrectly interpreted as a "No Database Selected".

If your query works fine in MySQL 8.0, that points to the possibility that Oracle has actually fixed this behavior (or at least gotten a better handle on it). Keep in mind that MariaDB is a completely different codebase.

[I have mentioned this crazy situation over the years in conjunction with doing DELETEs like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20DELETE%20SUBQUERY).

You may need to do one of two things:

1. Upgrade to the latest MariaDB (File a Bug Report if Needed)
2. Stick with MySQL 8.0

Comment: Ah, sorry: I forgot the **very nasty** thing: In phpMyAdmin the query works!! It fails just the preparation phase, but it execute if I don't have to prepare the query with a parameter! ;-)

Comment: Final consideration: I tested the same code / queries on MariaDB 10.6.4 and is still failing. So I definitively argue that the issue is MariaDB.

Comment: Please look also at their Jira: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26470